Correct Unzip of Excel file in Common Lisp
this is a follow up question to
Creating File with Square Brackets in the name in Common Lisp in a MacBook creates problems. How can I do it?
which I answered myself, since ChatGPT gave me the answer.
But on the way trying to unzip an Excel file (which contains a "[Content_Type].xml" file with square brackets in the name which create here the problem,
I realized that the zip library - with its unzip function also has a problem to unzip this square brackets name.
Source code of the unzip function is here https://github.com/mcna/zip/blob/master/zip.lisp
And it goes:
(defun unzip (pathname target-directory &key (if-exists :error) verbose)
  ;; <Xof> "When reading[1] the value of any pathname component, conforming
  ;;       programs should be prepared for the value to be :unspecific."
  (when (set-difference (list (pathname-name target-directory)
                              (pathname-type target-directory))
                        '(nil :unspecific))
    (error "pathname not a directory, lacks trailing slash?"))
  (with-zipfile (zip pathname)
    (do-zipfile-entries (name entry zip)
      (let ((filename (merge-pathnames name target-directory)))
        (ensure-directories-exist filename)
        (unless (char= (elt name (1- (length name))) #\/)
          (ecase verbose
            ((nil))
            ((t) (write-string name) (terpri))
            (:dots (write-char #\.)))
          (force-output)
          (with-open-file
              (s filename :direction :output :if-exists if-exists
               :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
            (zipfile-entry-contents entry s)))))))

Let's take an excel file.
And unzip it using this function.
I created manually an excel file. And then specified the path to it:
(defparameter *xlsx* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test.xlsx")
(ql:quickload :zip)
(zip:unzip *xlsx* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/")

It has exactly the same problem I encountered in my previous post.
bad place for a wild pathname
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLY's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD tid=5123 "sly-channel-1-mrepl-remote-1" RUNNING {70051404E3}>)

Backtrace:
 0: (SB-KERNEL::%FILE-ERROR #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml" "bad place for a wild pathname")
      Locals:
        ARGUMENTS = NIL
        DATUM = "bad place for a wild pathname"
        PATHNAME = #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml"
 1: (ENSURE-DIRECTORIES-EXIST #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml" :VERBOSE NIL :MODE 511)
      Locals:
        #:.DEFAULTING-TEMP. = NIL
        #:.DEFAULTING-TEMP.#1 = 511
        SB-IMPL::CREATED-P = NIL
        PATHNAME = #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml"
        SB-IMPL::PATHSPEC = #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml"
 2: (ZIP:UNZIP "/Users/josephus/Downloads/test.xlsx" "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/" :IF-EXISTS :ERROR :VERBOSE NIL :FORCE-UTF-8 NIL)
      Locals:
        #:.DEFAULTING-TEMP. = NIL
        FILENAME = #P"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/[Content_Types].xml"
        FORCE-UTF-8 = NIL
        IF-EXISTS = :ERROR
        PATHNAME = "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test.xlsx"
        TARGET-DIRECTORY = "/Users/josephus/Downloads/test_zip/"
        ZIP = #S(ZIP:ZIPFILE :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test.xlsx" {700888DB43}> :ENTRIES #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 11 {70088A23A3}>)
 3: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ZIP:UNZIP *XLSX* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 4: (EVAL (ZIP:UNZIP *XLSX* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/"))
 5: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))

Does anybody know how to handle this?
I asked chatGPT, and it suggested:
 (defun better-unzip (pathname target-directory &key (if-exists :error) verbose)
  "Unzip function that handles square brackets in filenames correctly."
  (zip:with-zipfile (zip pathname)
    (zip:do-zipfile-entries (name entry zip)
      (let ((filename (make-pathname :directory target-directory
                                     :name (pathname-name (parse-namestring name))
                                     :type (pathname-type (parse-namestring name)))))
        (ensure-directories-exist filename)
        (unless (char= (elt name (1- (length name))) #\/)
          (ecase verbose
            ((nil))
            ((t) (write-string name) (terpri))
            (:dots (write-char #\.)))
          (force-output)
          (with-open-file (s filename :direction :output :if-exists if-exists
                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
            (zip:zipfile-entry-contents entry s)))))))

I then did:
(better-unzip *xlsx* "/Users/<your-user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/")

But I encountered again:
bad place for a wild pathname
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLY's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD tid=5123 "sly-channel-1-mrepl-remote-1" RUNNING {70051404E3}>)

Backtrace:
 0: (SB-KERNEL::%FILE-ERROR #P"//Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip//[Content_Types].xml" "bad place for a wild pathname")
 1: (ENSURE-DIRECTORIES-EXIST #P"//Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip//[Content_Types].xml" :VERBOSE NIL :MODE 511)
 2: (BETTER-UNZIP "/Users/josephus/Downloads/test.xlsx" "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/" :IF-EXISTS :ERROR :VERBOSE NIL)
 3: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (BETTER-UNZIP *XLSX* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 4: (EVAL (BETTER-UNZIP *XLSX* "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/test_zip/"))
 5: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))


The underlying problem here is that you've crashed into the edges of the CL pathname specification.  Those edges are unfortunately never very far away.
In this case the problem is SBCL-specific, but it's not because SBCL has bugs: it's because SBCL does something it's allowed to do.
The very brief answer is almost that you need to either use or find something which turns strings into pathnames in a well-defined way for common platforms. And the practical answer is probably to use ASDF's UIOP, and in particular to use uiop:ensure-pathname whenever you wish to turn a string into a pathname.  This will arrange for things to work.  So if you modify the unzip function to be like this:
(defun unzip (pathname target-directory &key (if-exists :error) verbose)
  ;; <Xof> "When reading[1] the value of any pathname component, conforming
  ;;       programs should be prepared for the value to be :unspecific."
  (when (set-difference (list (pathname-name target-directory)
                              (pathname-type target-directory))
                        '(nil :unspecific))
    (error "pathname not a directory, lacks trailing slash?"))
  (with-zipfile (zip pathname)
    (do-zipfile-entries (name entry zip)
      (let ((filename (merge-pathnames (uiop:ensure-pathname name)
                                       target-directory)))
        (ensure-directories-exist filename)
        (unless (char= (elt name (1- (length name))) #\/)
          (ecase verbose
            ((nil))
            ((t) (write-string name) (terpri))
            (:dots (write-char #\.)))
          (force-output)
          (with-open-file
              (s filename :direction :output :if-exists if-exists
               :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
            (zipfile-entry-contents entry s)))))))

Then things will work.
Here is some debugging output from a version of what appears to be the current zip:
> (unzip "x.zip" #P"./")
name "x/", parsed name #P"./x/", not wild
name "x/a.a", parsed name #P"./x/a.a", not wild
name "x/[b].b", parsed name #P"./x/\\[b].b", not wild

Also, don't rely on ChatGPT: it's just not being helpful here, if it ever is.

Below are some details which I think are worth recording.
The specific problem is that SBCL (and I think SBCL only among current implementations) has an extended notion of what a wild pathname is.  It is allowed to do this.  So in SBCL the result of (parse-namestring "[foo].xml") is a wild pathname.  And in particular it is a wild pathname which matches "f.xml" and  "o.xml".  The same is true for this syntax used in other pathname components, and this syntax should be familiar from the syntax supported by many Unix shells, and indeed from regular expressions.
Now, in SBCL, if you construct a pathname with make-pathname and use only strings as components, you will not get a wild pathname.  So, for instance
> (wild-pathname-p (pathname "[foo].xml"))
t
> (wild-pathname-p (make-pathname :name "[foo]" :type "xml"))
nil
> (wild-pathname-p (pathname "foo.*"))
(:wild :wild-inferiors)
> (wild-pathname-p (make-pathname :name "foo" :type "*"))

So you can always construct a pathname this way which is not wild.  In order to construct a wild pathname you need to use some non-string value (like :wild).  I do not know if there is a way to construct the thing corresponding to [abc] other than by grabbing it from another pathname: I can't find any mention of this in the SBCL manual.
However this fails horribly to be portable.  The CLHS says in 19.2.2.3:

[...] conforming programs must be prepared to encounter any of the following additional values in any component or any element of a list that is the directory component:

The symbol :wild, which matches anything.
A string containing implementation-dependent special wildcard characters.
Any object, representing an implementation-dependent wildcard pattern.


[My emphasis]
The second case means that yes, a pathname is allowed to have components which are strings but still be wild.
It is, perhaps, possible to argue that if you provide a string as a pathname component to make-pathname then that pathname is not allowed to be wild in that component.  I don't think the spec really says this, and I think it probably can't, because I would expect that if some pathname p has a wild name then (make-pathname :name (pathname-name a) :type "foo")) also has a wild name.  Yet, from above, the wild name can be a string.
SBCL on the other hand appears to take the sensible approach that if you provide a string for a component in make-pathname, that component is never wild.  This is the right thing to do, I think.
However none of this is going to help you much: zip files (and many other sorts of files) contain pathnames represented as strings.  Something at the Lisp level needs to parse those pathnames.  And if those pathnames look wild, it will parse them as wild pathnames.  There may be specific workarounds, as I think Rainer has given you, but in general I think the only solution to this problem is either to implement your own pathname parsing (horrible) or to rely on someone else to have done that for you.  And in this case the ASDF people have done it for you.

Thank you a lot for the long answer! You answered, while I was figuring out what I wrote in my answer. At least for SBCL I found a solution. But I guess it is implementation specific. I found out that the correct way to escape in this way is:
#P"~/a/b/\\[some_name].xml". This \\[...] was very unintuitive.

You should create a pull request for this in the zip package! it will be helpful for us all.

did you try it in the zip package's code? the simple correction unfortunately doesn't work out as I thought.

I created a new answer which shows the code which corrects the unzip. This works.
It seems the uiop:ensure-pathname doesn't help when it is called upon name which comes from zip::do-zipfile-entries (probably because that itself uses the pathname system inside CL?
My functions use (format nil "~a" path) to make plain string out of the path objects again. And They are used to dissect the path to recreate a new path with the make-pathname function. This then handles the  [ ] in the name correctly.

it seems that UIOP:ensure-pathname handles plain path strings correctly for each implementation. But it can't correct #P"..." objects which are already read-in and interpreted by the pathname system in common lisp. my `path-string-" functions by going down again to string level can "correct" #P"..." objects which "misinterpreted" [ ] already.

I just saw that zip library is listed amongst the orphaned libraries
https://common-lisp.net/phub
is this list really correct? Or is common-lisp.net itself orphaned?

Perhaps you are using a very old version of zip?  My patch is against the current version and I can confirm it works.  I have added debugging output to the answer to show this.

Thank you! I see your pull request in zip package was accepted now.

I would call
(ensure-directories-exist #p"/Users/foo/dir/")

instead of
(ensure-directories-exist #p"/Users/foo/dir/[a].b")


Thank you for the hint! So then ...
(ensure-directories-exist (make-pathname :directory (pathname-directory #P"/Users/foo/dir/[a].b")))
this works!

This removes the error. However, I realized the problem are the pathname- functions which interprete [ and ] as a pattern.

By trial and error I now just found out that first converting a path #P"..." into a plain string through (format nil "~a" path) and then writing string-based path functions for the first solved the issue. I will post it in a new answer. However, I guess it is not a good idea to fall back to string manipulations ... (not sure how this would work in windows).

Currently, I found this fix (in the state that the zip package as it is stays unchanged).
(ql:quickload :uiop)
(ql:quickload :zip)

;;;; my correction functions only valid for SBCL

(defun path-to-string (path)
  "Convert Path to plain string expanding `~` correctly."
  (let* ((path-string (format nil "~a" path))
     (pos (position #\? path-string)))
    (if (and pos (zerop pos))
    (concatenate 'string (uiop:getenv "HOME") (subseq path-string 1))
        path-string)))

(Defun path-string-directory (path &key (sep #\/))
  "Return parent directory string ending with `/`."
  (let* ((path-string (path-to-string path))
     (pos (position sep (reverse path-string))))
    (if pos
    (subseq path-string 0 (- (length path-string) (position sep (reverse path-string))))
    (uiop/os:getcwd)))) ;; current working directory

(defun path-string-last (path &key (sep #\/))
  "Return last element of a path-string - directory or file."
  (let* ((path-string (path-to-string path))
     (pos (position sep (reverse path-string))))
    (if pos
    (subseq path-string (- (length path-string) (position sep (reverse path-string))))
    path-string)))

(defun path-string-name (path &key (sep #\/))
  "Return name component of filename (before last dot)."
  (let ((last-part (path-string-last path :sep sep))
        (sep-type #\.))
    (subseq last-part 0 (- (length last-part) (position sep-type (reverse last-part)) 1))))

(defun path-string-type (path &key (sep #\/))
  "Return type portion of filename (after last dot)."
  (let ((last-part (path-string-last path :sep sep))
        (sep-type #\.))
    (subseq last-part (- (length last-part) (position sep-type (reverse last-part))))))

(defun path-string-make (path &key (directory nil) (sep #\/))
  "Return corrected path object of a path or path string by treating brackets as plain
     text."
  (make-pathname :directory (or directory (path-string-directory path :sep sep))
                 :name (path-string-name path :sep sep)
                 :type (path-string-type path :sep sep)))

#|
(defun create-test-file (path &key (text "<H1/>"))
  "If this works without error, square brackets are treated correctly by the system."
  (with-open-file (stream (ensure-directories-exist path)
                          :direction :output
                          :if-does-not-exist :create
                          :if-exists :supersede)
    (format stream "~a" text)))
|#


;;;; This is part of zip package which I need to call to correct the unzip function

(defun %zipfile-entry-contents (entry stream)
  (zip::with-latin1 ()
    (let ((s (zip::zipfile-entry-stream entry))
      header)
      (file-position s (zip::zipfile-entry-offset entry))
      (setf header (zip::make-local-header s))
      (assert (= (zip::file/signature header) #x04034b50))
      (file-position s (+ (zip::file-position s)
              (zip::file/name-length header)
              (zip::file/extra-length header)))
      (let ((in (make-instance 'zip::truncating-stream
                   :input-handle s
                   :size (zip::zipfile-entry-compressed-size entry)))
        (outbuf nil)
        out)
    (if stream
        (setf out stream)
        (setf outbuf (zip::make-byte-array (zip::zipfile-entry-size entry))
          out (zip::make-buffer-output-stream outbuf)))
    (ecase (zip::file/method header)
      (0 (zip::store in out))
      (8 (zip::inflate in out)))
    outbuf))))

(defun %%zipfile-entry-contents (entry &optional stream)
  (if (pathnamep stream)
      (with-open-file (s (path-string-make stream)
             :direction :output
             :if-exists :supersede
                         :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
    (%zipfile-entry-contents entry s))
      (%zipfile-entry-contents entry stream)))


(defun better-unzip (pathname target-directory &key (if-exists :error) verbose)
  ;; <Xof> "When reading[1] the value of any pathname component, conforming
  ;;       programs should be prepared for the value to be :unspecific."
  (when (set-difference (list (pathname-name target-directory)
                              (pathname-type target-directory))
                        '(nil :unspecific))
    (error "pathname not a directory, lacks trailing slash?"))
  (zip:with-zipfile (zip pathname)
    (zip:do-zipfile-entries (name entry zip)
      (let ((filename (path-string-make name :directory target-directory)))
        (ensure-directories-exist filename)
        (unless (char= (elt name (1- (length name))) #\/)
          (ecase verbose
            ((nil))
            ((t) (write-string name) (terpri))
            (:dots (write-char #\.)))
          (force-output)
          (with-open-file
              (s filename :direction :output :if-exists if-exists
               :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
            (%%zipfile-entry-contents entry s)))))))

This better-unzip function works in MacOS and Linux, when :zip and :uiop are quickloaded. And this code given for correction.l
(defparameter *xlsx* "/path/to/your/file.xlsx")
(better-unzip *xlsx* "/path/to/your/target/dir/")

I haven't tested Windows yet. And neither other implementations than SBCL.
